# Bootstrap4 vertical align column

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

Is there a quick flexbox classes to vertically align content within columns?

For example

```
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        unknown height
      </div>
      <div class="col h100 d-flex justify-content-center">
        set same height as previous + flex center
      </div>
  </div>
```

Above doesnt obviously work but you get the point...

Same height rows can be achieved with this https://scotch.io/quick-tips/different-tricks-on-how-to-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height#toc-option-4-use-flexbox

-> Does not feel the smoothest solution, isnt there native bootstrap class?

And well its still not aligned middle

Comment: true but no clean answer to the problem...

Answer (score 1):

ok this is enough:

```
<div class="row align-items-center"></div>
```